# Qual a diferença entre os vários tipos de JOIN do SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, join

No SQL exitem vários tipos de `JOIN`, qual a diferença entre `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` e `FULL JOIN`?

Comment: Talvez ajude em algo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/6454

Comment: Ajudou, mas faltou a explicação do `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Compreendo @Bacco seria bom fechar por duplicata.

Comment: @Florida aproveitei e acrescentei o cross na minha também, assim fica mais completinha ;) - qualquer dúvida deixe comment lá, que eu tento esclarecer se puder. Eu tava enrolando pra por, pq não tinha imaginado como fazer o gráfico, mas acho que hoje eu consegui uma solução razoável

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo minimalista, e considerando que A sempre é a tabela à esquerda, e B à direita:

`Inner Join` = apenas registros ligados nas tabelas A e B

`Left Join` = todos os registros de A, apenas os registros ligados de B.

`Right Join` = todos os registros de B, apenas os registros ligados de A.

`Cross Join` = todos os registros ligados de A e B, todas as linhas de A e todas as linhas de B, além de réplicas das linhas de A e B com variações entre registros das mesmas tabelas.

`Full Join` = Left Join e Right Join juntos. As linhas que não são ligadas não aparecem.

Links:

[Full join e Cross Join](http://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-full-join-cross-join-update-e-delete-associacao-de-tabelas-sql-server-2008-parte-3/18931)

[Outros joins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/6454)